# dynamic memory allocation using the stack not the heap in C

Tags: c

I have write a small code to dynamicly allocate the memory size needed to store the full input, but using the heap with malloc and realloc

Is there any way i can do it just using the stack to store the full user input in memory ?

the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int c = 0;
    int buffer_length = 2;
    int buffer_pos = 0;
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(buffer_length * sizeof(char));

    while(c != 10){
        c = getchar();

        if(buffer_pos >= buffer_length - 1){
            buffer_length += 2;
            buffer = realloc(buffer, buffer_length * sizeof(char));
        }

        buffer[buffer_pos] = c;
        buffer_pos++;
    }

    printf("%s",buffer);

    free(buffer);
    main(0,NULL);

}
```

Comment: You're multiplying by the wrong size, it should be `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: Why ? i'm using **char*** buffer, not **char** buffer

Comment: `char *` is a pointer to an array of characters, not a pointer to character pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible in the stack.

You can use a variable-length array to allocate a local array whose size comes from an expression. But once it's allocated, you can't change the size.

If you need to resize the array, you have to use dynamic allocation with `malloc()` and `realloc()`.